# Authentication issue using requests on aspx site

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to use requests (python) to grab some pages from a website that requires me to be logged in.
I did inspect the login page to check out the username and password headers. But I found the names for those fields are not the standard 'username', 'password' used by most sites as you can see from the below screenshots

[password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/assO1.jpg)

I used them that way in my python script but each time I get a 'wrong syntax' error. Even sublimetext displayed a part of the name in orange as you can see from the pix below

From this I know there must be some problem with the name. But try to escape the $ signs did not help.
Even the login.aspx header disappears before google chrome could register it on the network.

The site is www dot bncnetwork dot net

I'd be happy if someone could help me figure out what to do about this.

Here is the code`import requests

```
import requests

def get_project_page(seed_page):

   username = "*******************"
   password = "*******************"

   bnc_login = dict(ctl00$MainContent$txtEmailID=username, ctl00$MainContent$txtPassword=password)
   sess_req = requests.Session()
   sess_req.get(seed_page)
   sess_req.post(seed_page, data=bnc_login, headers={"Referer":"http://www.bncnetwork.net/MyBNC.aspx"})

page = sess_req.get(seed_page)

return page.text`
```

Comment: Please take the time to include the relevant code directly in your question as text, not a link to a screenshot. This will make it much easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I've done that. I thought the image would show up on the page. Turns out it didn't. Is that why you voted me down, cos I'm thinking so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use strings for the keys, the $ will cause a syntax error if you don't:

```
  data = {"ctl00$MainContent$txtPassword":password, "ctl00$MainContent$txtEmailID":email}
```

There are evenvalidation fileds etc.. to be filled in also, follow the logic from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554235/scraping-excel-from-website-using-python-with-dopostback-link-url-hidden/38557881#38557881) to fill them out, all the fields can be seen in chrome tools:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have followed the link and taken a look at what was done in that case. I followed another link from there dealing with aspx form authentication and I've gotten the hang of it. But the problem is that in my case I don't know how to see the FormData. The login.aspx form in the google chrome network monitor disappears almost as soon as I log in. Is there a work around to this? I've tried searching but not getting any luck so far.

Comment: I have some thoughts I'd like to share. Lessons learned and further questions. I'll split it into 2 or more separate comments cos of character limit  first lesson: of all the plenty info available in the form only the ones in CAPS and two leading underscores are required in our post request. They are contained in <input> tags
second lesson: when i check the html source i found that these inputs tags have following attributes: type, name, id, value
third lesson: some of these values don't have any value, e.g __EVENTTARGET. Some have eg. __VIEWSTATE always has.

Comment: I happen to have the following fields in the site I want to scrape __LASTFOCUS:, __EVENTTARGET:, __EVENTARGUMENT:, __VIEWSTATE:, __EVENTVALIDATION:, __ASYNCPOST: in that order.
fourth lesson: we have to re-validate our POST request each time we send it. But this is where I get lost. I don't understand the Validate function you defined in the post where you directed me, especially the last line. But here is my guess: you are creating a beautiful soup object of the homepage and from there you extract the value of __VIEWSTATE.

Comment: I think this is a good way because I have seen the page you referred to and the __VIEWSTATE input has a really long value. 
Also, I would like to know if the __VIEWSTATE value changes between calls or whether it is constant. If it is constant I can just copy mine into my script. Same with __EVENTVALIDATION
Also, I don't understand the last line in your validate function. I think that is the key for me.
Please do help and thanks